# C Program Crashing... 'Read in and Output Various Data Types'

Tags: c

**Updated**

I am having some trouble with *Question 2* on *Chapter 4* from *"A Guide to C Programming"* by Paul Kelly.

As far as I can tell, my syntax is correct, however when the program reaches line 36 the program auto fills the `scanf();` variable slots.

I can not seem to find a solution to this problem anywhere.

Here is my code. I have put a marker beside line 36

---

```
/* 
   Program to demonstrate single scanf function
   to read various data types and output results.

*/  
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int first;
    int second, third, fourth;
    float principle, rate, time;
    char keyVal1, keyVal2;
    char c;
    int i;
    float f;
    double d;

    printf("\nPlease Enter an Integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &first);
    printf("\nYou Entered %d\n", first);

    printf("\nThank You, Please Enter 3 more integers\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &second, &third, &fourth);
    printf("\nYou Entered %d %d and %d\n", second, third, fourth);

    printf("\nGreat, 
            now please enter decimal values for principle, 
           rate and time.\n");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &principle, &rate, &time);
    printf("\nYou Entered %.2f %.2f and %.2f\n", principle, rate, time);

    printf("\nPlease Enter any 2 characters\n");
    scanf(" %c %c", &keyVal1, &keyVal2);
    printf("\nYou Entered %c and %c\n", keyVal1, keyVal2); 

    // ***36     
    printf("\nNow Enter any other character, 
            followed by an integer and 2 decimal numbers\n");***
    scanf(" %c %d %f %lf ",&c, &i, &f, &d);
    printf("\nYour character was %c.\nYour integer was %d\nYour 
           decimal numbers were %.2f and %.2lf\n", c, i, f, d);     
}
```

Comment: try  scanf with space before " %s" , scanf(" %c",&a);

Comment: Yep, tried that also, but doesn't work. Thanks for your response

Comment: when posting a modification to the code, post a new code block.  Otherwise the prior answers/comments are misleading/meaningless as they refer to code that is no longer part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%1s %1s", &keyVal1, &keyVal2);
```

Use `%c` specifier instead of `%1s` .

```
scanf(" %c %c", &keyVal1, &keyVal2);
```

Similarly ,

```
scanf("%c %d %f %lf ",&c, &i, &f, &d);
```

leave a space before `%c` -

```
scanf(" %c %d %f %lf ",&c, &i, &f, &d);
```

You need to leave space because as `ENTER` is pressed after previous `scanf` `'\n'` remains in `stdin` .

Comment: I tried using %c. While the program no longer crashes, there is a bug. The rest of the variables in the remaining scanf(); functions are auto filled and the program closes automatically. Thanks for your reply though. Much appreciated

Comment: @Phil  A space is left before `%c` . Try this once . That space will matter here.

Comment: Yep I put the space. Now what happens is the program requires me to enter the 2 chars twice before crashing?? I'm lost lol. Thanks again mate

Comment: @Phil  I don't know if you did or not . But last `scanf` shuld also have a space as I mentioned in answer.

Comment: @Phil  Is this your real code because now it seem to work correctly.

Comment: yes this is my real code. I am looking for help. Not here to troll. Maybe it is a problem with my system then but I can't understand how that would work

Answer (score 0):

```
 scanf("%1s %1s", &keyVal1, &keyVal2);
```

it should be...

```
 scanf(" %c %c", &keyVal1, &keyval2);
```

you need to use the `c` identifier, that will end the crashing, now after you do that you'll notice that the first character doesn't seem to be read in. This is  because you have a `printf()` right before, so your `scanf()` will read in the last `char` in the `printf()` which was the `\n` character. We have to fix this by putting a space before the identifier, so it won't read in the last value in stdin.
Also you need to change the `printf()` statements to the same identifiers otherwise an 'undefined action will occur'.

Also, the last `scanf()` change it to this...

```
 scanf(" %c %d %f %lf",&c, &i, &f, &d);
```

By taking out the space in after the last identifier, the program works well.

Comment: printf("\nPlease Enter any 2 characters\n");
    scanf(" %c %c ", &keyVal1, &keyVal2);
    printf("\nYou Entered %c and %c\n", keyVal1, keyVal2); 
    
    printf("\nNow Enter any other character, followed by an integer and 2 decimal numbers\n");
    scanf(" %c %d %f %lf ",&c, &i, &f, &d);
    printf("\nYour character was %c.\nYour integer was %d\nYour decimal numbers were %.2f and %.2lf\n", c, i, f, d);
    
    
    
}//end main

Comment: that is the updated code with the proper spacing, but it doesn't seem to fix the bug. The program still auto fills the remaining variables and closes. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Apologies if the first comment is hard to read. Have edited the code in the original post to show my changes.

Comment: @Phil it seems to be working fine for me... What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Phil Updated my answer, added the last 3 lines.

Comment: I am using Borland as advised by our lecturer. I havn't yet tried it in Eclipse but I will now. Is Borland known for being buggy?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with this line:

```
scanf(" %c %d %f %lf ",&c, &i, &f, &d);
```

the space at the end of the format string means that all 'white space' is consumed until a non-white space character is encountered in the input stream.

so the scanf() never completes until a non white space character is entered by the user, after entering the 4 requested values.

To fix the problem, remove the trailing space in the format string.

```
scanf(" %c %d %f %lf",&c, &i, &f, &d);
```